# How to wirelessly push files to Android using ADB via Windows context menu?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, context-menu, adb

By using context menu in Windows I would like to wirelessly push selected file(s) to Android device using ADB.

I want to connect to the device, push selected file(s) and disconnect each time, so I crated this simple batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
D:\adb.exe connect 192.168.0.103:5555
D:\adb.exe push "%%~f1" /sdcard/
D:\adb.exe disconnect
```

The command in context menu points to my batch file:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ADB_Push_to_Phone]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ADB_Push_to_Phone\command]
@="D:\\Tools\\CMD\\ADB_PUSH_TO_PHONE.cmd"
```

Running this as intended (right click on file -> ADB_Push_to_Phone) gives this error at the push command:

```
adb: error: cannot stat '%~f1': No such file or directory
```

How do I expand properly the selected file(s) full path inside this command? Or is it a different issue here with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set context menu command to:

```
"D:\Tools\CMD\ADB_PUSH_TO_PHONE.cmd" "%1"
```

And to modify push command in batch file:

```
D:\adb.exe push %1 /sdcard/
```

Answer (score 1):

If I take a look at a file association for the GIMP image editor, the command line is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.10.exe" "%1"
```

You don’t have the `"%1"` part in your command line. If you add it, this should work. The complete command could look like this:

```
D:\Tools\CMD\ADB_PUSH_TO_PHONE.cmd "%1"
```

(Note that I am not using any escaping that would be required in `.reg` files.)

To diagnose things, I recommend debug prints in your batch file and possibly using the `pause` or `timeout` commands to have time to look at them.

Answer (score 1):

> *adb: error: cannot stat **`'%~f1'`**: No such file or directory*

There is no expansion for **`%1` in `%~f1`** for any registry arguments:

```bat
Arguments:

%1, %D, %H, %I, %L, %S, %V, %W

Not Work/Expand:

%~nx1, %~nxD, %~nxH, %~nxI, %~nxL, %~nxS, %~nxV, %~nxW

 
Often we find "%1" in the commands associated with file types

(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FileType\shell\open\command).

In Windows 9x through 2000 (and possibly XP) this would evaluate

to the short notation of the fully qualified path of the file of type FileType.

To get the long file name, use "%L" instead of "%1".
```

When using `right click on file -> ADB_Push_to_Phone`, the selected file has to be passed to your `.bat`, it doesn't come `automatically`, it is first "passed" from the register to `.bat` as an argument.

You are already treating the path, passing it as complete by right click to windows registry in "%V", so you can use "%~1", since the argument received in your bat file.

---

```bat
@echo off

cd /d "%~d0"
adb.exe connect 192.168.0.103:5555
adb.exe push "%~1" /sdcard/
adb.exe disconnect
```

---

In the Windows registry (or `.reg` file) use:

```bat
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ADB_Push_to_Phone]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ADB_Push_to_Phone\command]
@=\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe\" /q /c \"D:\\Tools\\CMD\\ADB_PUSH_TO_PHONE.cmd\" \"%L\"\"
```

Your bat can go straight to where the executable is, without the need to edit the path for each drive/volume change, use `cd /d "drive_where_your_bat_is"`:

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "%~d0"

adb.exe connect 192.168.0.103:5555
adb.exe push "%~1" /sdcard/
adb.exe disconnect
```

---

- Or use `drive_where_your_bat_is:` + `\adb.exe`

```bat
@echo off 

%~d0\adb.exe connect 192.168.0.103:5555
%~d0\adb.exe push "%~1" /sdcard/
%~d0\adb.exe disconnect
```